# has anyone debugged Conway's Fractran program for digits of pi?

Tags: pi, math-software

Title says it all.   I found an old email thread at [this site](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esillke/NEWS/fractran)  in which Conway (and others) speculate on the location and cause of the bug, but I have not found a published update.  Is there any news on this front?

Comment: There's not much context or significance here. Does it really matter if this random broken program has been debugged? What does this do for our math knowledge?

Comment: @kevinkayaks  I posted here vs., say some *software.SE  site because I found more Fractran-related posts here than anywhere else.    Fractran as a language certainly highlights some fun branches of computational math!

Comment: Since Bill Dubuque (presumably the same one, though I cannot guarantee it) has been a significant contributor to this forum, there is the possibility of asking him directly.